# In C++ when to use WCHAR and when to use CHAR

Tags: c++, unicode

I have a question:

Some libraries use WCHAR as the text parameter and others use CHAR (as UTF-8): I need to know when to use WCHAR or CHAR when I write my own library.

Comment: WCHAR stands for wide char, usually used when dealing with the UNICODE encoding style of text AFAIK

Comment: There is no `WCHAR` in C++. Do you mean the `WCHAR` macro defined by the Windows headers?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I assumed he meant WCHAR of Win32 headers (in fact, I was thinking of editing the OP's tags adding [winapi] :)

Comment: WCHAR isn't always Unicode - it could be DBCS, especially when dealing with character sets like Shift-JIS and BIG5.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `char` and treat it as UTF-8. There are a great many reasons for this; this website summarises it much better than I can:

http://utf8everywhere.org/

It recommends converting from `wchar_t` to `char` (UTF-16 to UTF-8) as soon as you receive it from any library, and converting back when you need to pass strings to it. So to answer your question, always use `char` except at the point that an API requires you to pass or receive `wchar_t`.

Comment: Actually, it says to use UTF-8 "if an application is not supposed to specialize in text".  I tend to use UTF-8 pretty much everywhere, but I'm not sure it would be appropriate in an editor, for example.  Things like regular expressions will be significantly slower if you use UTF-8, for example.

Comment: Good point; you're right. It sounds like this won't make a difference to the OP but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: @BenHymers Are you trying to say that UTF-8 takes 8 bits to encode any UNICODE codepoint? For example, code point range, `U+10000-U+10FFFF`, UTF-8 says, it takes 4 bytes to encode a codepoint. I have no idea on the meaning, when u say, take `char` and treat it as UTF-8. How can `char` store UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @overexchange No, I'm definitely not saying that, I don't think anyone would accept such an answer :) We're talking about strings rather than single characters - so an array of `char` rather than a single `char` - I just omitted 'array of' for brevity as it's implied in this context. Each `char` is one byte of a UTF-8 symbol which may be one byte or more.

Comment: @overexchange Are you asking what an array of `char` looks like? It can be as simple as `char*`. I don't think that's what you really mean though since anyone quoting codepoint ranges must surely know what an array is ;) Can you be more specific?

Comment: @BenHymers you mean `char*` pointing to string? for each UTF-8 code character?

Comment: @overexchange That's one representation of a sequence of bytes in C++, yes - there are others (e.g. `std::string`). The `char*` doesn't "point to a string", it points to the first character of a string, and the next memory address is the next character and so on, usually (by convention) terminated by a null (0) character. If this string is UTF-8, each of these `char`s is one byte which may be a whole Unicode char, or part of one. Honestly though, without intending to cause offence, you need to go back to the very basics of C++ before trying to understand how to represent Unicode in it!

Comment: @BenHymers For knowing to simply use `char*`, why `wchar` was introduce, when `wchar` is not portable?

Comment: @overexchange You'll have to ask whoever added it to the standard! I believe it's a mistake, and so do many others: http://utf8everywhere.org/ - the reason is probably that somebody once thought "two bytes per character should be plenty".

Comment: @BenHymers  So I should ignore reading such [documentations](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Character-Set-Handling.html#Character-Set-Handling)  provided by GNUC.

Comment: @overexchange What are you doing? Are you trolling me? You're asking extremely basic questions then referencing detailed documents. I've been very patient so far but now it looks like you're just passive-aggresively trying to make yourself look smarter than me, not genuinely asking for help. The GNU documentation you provide is talking about GNU C specifically, where `wchar_t` is 32 bits - this isn't standard and can't be relied on on other platforms and compilers. I'm not going to reply any more - apparently I'm wasting my time since you're knee-deep in documentation already. Good luck.

Comment: @BenHymers No I was just seeking help in understanding better. I did not expect(assume) that you would get bothered so badly. I apologize for this.

Comment: the advise in this thread is just WRONG... because you can't generalize a practice for all use cases.  The real advise is it depends...  I wrote a string class that, internally, uses wchar_t so I can convert to unicode if needed.  The public API accepts char * and converts to wchar_t (internally) And while this class works for most of my work, I don't think I would use it on an embedded platform where space and speed are typically primary objectives.  Desktop and even mobile apps my wchar_t based library is OK (again depends) but for code running on a small M4 ARM, probably not.

Answer (score 12):

`WCHAR` (or `wchar_t` on Visual C++ compiler) is used for **Unicode UTF-16** strings.
This is the "native" string encoding used by Win32 APIs.

`CHAR` (or `char`) can be used for several other string formats: ANSI, MBCS, UTF-8.

Since UTF-16 is the *native* encoding of Win32 APIs, you may want to use `WCHAR` (and better a proper string class based on it, like `std::wstring`) at the Win32 API boundary, inside your app.

And you can use UTF-8 (so, `CHAR`/`char` and `std::string`) to exchange your Unicode text outside your application boundary. For example: UTF-8 is widely used on the Internet, and when you exchange UTF-8 text between different platforms you don't have the problem of endianness (instead with UTF-16 you have to consider both the UTF-16BE *big-endian* and the UTF-16LE *little-endian* cases).

You can convert between UTF-16 and UTF-8 using the `WideCharToMultiByte()` and `MultiByteToWideChar()` Win32 APIs. These are pure-C APIs, and these can be conveniently wrapped in C++ code, using string classes instead of raw character pointers, and exceptions instead of raw error codes. You can find an example of that [here](https://github.com/GiovanniDicanio/Win32StringConversions).

Comment: @Mgetz: I know that. In fact, I assumed the OP meant WCHAR as defined in Win32 SDK headers, and his question was about the Win32 environment. Note that I wrote: _"`WCHAR` (or `wchar_t` **on Visual C++ compiler**)"_.

Comment: In fact, wchar_t does not store any encoding information at all. It is a type that is always wider (more bytes per word) than a char.

Comment: @Mr.C64 That seems to be a common assumption, one that I wouldn't make as the OP has not specified a compiler.

Comment: are you sure it's UTF-16 in windows and not UCS-2 ?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira Actually `wchar_t` is not necessarily any wider than `char`. The only requirement is that `wchar_t` be large enough to store a unique value for every member of the largest character set supported by an implementation. So if an implementation's largest character set is smaller than 256 then `wchar_t` can be 8 bits.

Comment: @AlexDan Yes, Window APIs use `wchar_t` to store UTF-16, including characters outside the BMP. It's somewhat ambiguous whether this behavior conforms to the C++ specification.

Comment: @AlexDan: If you go back far enough (NT4 I think) then it was UCS-2, but it's been UTF-16 ever since.

Comment: Great mention of `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()`! Very helpful ^_^

Answer (score 4):

The right question is not which type to use, but what should be your contract with your library users. Both char and wchar_t can mean more than one thing.

The right answer to me, is use char and consider everything utf-8 encoded, as utf8everywhere.org suggests. This will also make it easier to write cross-platform libraries.

Make sure you make correct use of strings though. Some APIs like fopen(), would accept a char* string and treat it differently (not as UTF-8) when compiled on Windows. If Unicode is important to you (and it probably is, when you are dealing with strings), be sure to handle your strings correctly. A good example can be seen in boost::locale. I also recommend using boost::nowide on Windows to get strings handled correctly inside your library.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows we stick to WCHARS. std::wstring. Mainly because if you don't you end up having to convert because calling Windows functions.

I have a feeling that trying to use utf8 internally simply because of http://utf8everywhere.org/ is gonna bite us in the bum later on down the line.

Answer (score 0):

It is best recommended that, when developing a Windows application, resort to TCHARs. The good thing about TCHARs is that they can be either regular chars or wchars, depending whether the unicode setting is set or not. Once you resort to TCHARs, you make sure that all string manipulations that you use also start with the _t prefix (e.g. _tcslen for length of string). That way you will know that your code will work both in Unicode and ASCII environments.

Comment: `TCHAR` and the ability to switch between `char` and `wchar_t` were useful for migrating legacy programs from legacy encoded `char` to `wchar_t`. `TCHAR` should not be used for any other purpose. New software should not be written with `TCHAR`: new Windows code should explicitly use either (UTF-8 encoded) `char` , or `wchar_t`.

Comment: The really bad thing about `TCHAR` is that it can be either `char` or `wchar_t`, since you have to write distinctively different code depending on which one you use.  Whatever you choose (and frankly, unless you are doing text processing, it should be `char`), use it, and not `TCHAR`.

Comment: @armanali Which encoding format?  You have to handle whatever encoding format you receive.  If it's UTF-8, then you write code which handles UTF-8; it it's UTF-16 (BE or LE), then you write code which handles UTF-16; if it's UTF-32 (BE or LE), then you write code which handles UTF-32.

Comment: I would say it is very bad to use setting-sensitive types (As TCHAR, which depend on UNICODE define) in a library. The question is about a library. Agree with utf8everywhere.org.

Answer (score 0):

I will refer mainly to C below but all of this also applies to C++, which is a language of its own (it's NOT a superset of C! It's only similar and partially compatible to C), but initially started as an extension to C before it became an own language and is thus heavily influenced by C.

The C standards know nothing about encoding. A string in C used to be a sequence of bytes, assuming that every character fits into a single byte, so you have up to 255 different characters, as the character 0 is reserved for end-of-string marker. This is fine for ASCII as well as western encodings (e.g. ISO Latin-x encodings, Windows-1252, etc.). C does not try to interpret these characters in any way, it's just a string of bytes and it's up to the system how to interpret those bytes.

But when C became widespread and international, there was a problem: Languages like Japanese, Indian, Korean, Chinese, Vietnamese have more than 255 different characters. There existed encodings for those language as well but those encodings used 2 bytes per character. So wide characters were introduced that were at least 2 bytes long (but can also be longer than that) and that can be used to represent characters with 16 bit encoding. Just as before, C itself knows nothing about encoding and doesn't care how the characters were encoded.

Fast forward to today: Meanwhile pretty much all classic encodings are today as we now have Unicode. Unicode is a characters set that has room for about one million characters (1'114'112 if you want to be exact), enough to encode all characters of all languages currently in active use on earth. But Unicode is just a huge character table that maps numbers to characters, how those numbers are encoded in bytes is a different question. The encoding used is up to implementers but to provide interoperability between different implementations and a stable file storage format, there are 3 standard encodings defined: UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 (UTF means Unicode Transformation Format)

In UTF-32 every character is represented as a 32 bit value. C has no equivalent for this, so let's ignore that encoding here (although wide characters can be 32 bit per character, the standard does not forbid that IIRC). Of course, 32 bit is overkill, 24 bits (3 bytes) would have been sufficient but computers and programmers don't like 3 byte values (if you ever had to work with RGB, you know that working with RGBA is way easier).

In UTF-16 each character is either represented by 2 or 4 bytes. The most important characters are presented as 16 bit value and would fit into a single 16 bit wide char. However, 16 bit has only room for 65536 characters, not enough for the over 1 million available ones. So to represent less common ones, a trick is used: The character is represented using two UTF-16 characters, so called surrogates. Surrogate characters on their own define no character, they always come in pairs and each surrogate pair encodes a single character outside of the basic plane. Unicode orders characters into 16 [planes](https://unicodeplus.com/plane). Most of them are unused and all the important characters of wide spread languages are found in the first one, the basic plane. You will hardly ever come across surrogates in normal modern texts with one exception: Emojis and pictograms (e.g. arrows, markers, etc.) are in plane 1 (Supplementary Multilingual Plane). Also characters for some very uncommon (like tribe languages) and historic languages (old Indian, old Arabian, Ancient Greek, etc.) can be found there.

Side note: One thing I will ignore for the rest of the reply is endianess. UTF16 can be little (UTF-16LE) or big endian (UTF-16BE), but again, that's just an implementation detail, depending on your platform and maybe your CPU. An Unicode library can always handle both and for text files, there is a way to detect the endianness by placing a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) character at the very beginning of the file. This can also be used to detect whether it is UTF-16 at all or rather UTF-8 or UTF-32.

The most important encoding today is UTF-8. In UTF-8 a character can be represented by any number of 1 to 4 bytes. The most common characters will use 1 (e.g. English) or 2 bytes (most western languages, Arabic, Cyrillic, etc.), except for Asian languages, that will usually require 3 bytes per character. 4 bytes are only required when you need to go beyond the basic plane. UTF-8 is so popular as it comes with a "built-in" compression (the majority of C strings in code are just ASCII strings and here only one byte per character is used, whereas UTF-16 would always use 2 bytes per character, requiring twice as much RAM) and as long as your code does not perform any work on strings, UTF-8 will work fine with any C APIs designed for just 8 bit characters.

You only need to be careful when you do things like cutting, splitting or trimming strings, as you must not assume that every `char` or `wchar_t` in fact represents a single character. If you cut anywhere in a string, you might cut in the middle of a character (e.g. if you cut between two surrogate characters in UTF-16 or anywhere within a multi-byte character in UTF-8). Also to make things even more complicated, even if you understand UTF-8/16 encoding correctly in your code, you still cannot cut/split/trim correctly, as a character can be built up out of multiple characters.

E.g. the German Umlaut ö can either be the Unicode character 0xF6 (UTF-16 `0x00 0xF6`, UTF-8 `0xC3 0xB6`) or it can be composed out of o (Unicode character 0x6F, UTF-16 `0x00 0x6F`, UTF-8 `0x6F`) and ¨(Unicode character 0xA8, UTF-16 `0x00 0xA8`, UTF-8 `0xC2 0xA8`). Both would look like `ö` on the screen, both represent the same glyph. There is no one-to-one mapping between Unicode characters in a string and glyphs represented by that string. A single glyph can be made out of multiple Unicode characters and this can also be more than two (multiple so called "modifier symbols" can be combined on top of each other). So already comparing two strings byte by byte may lead to incorrect results, as even though the byte sequence may be different, those strings may still represent the same set of glyphs and a user would expect them to compare equal, since they do look equal on screen.

Unicode is super complex and the moment you want to deal with Unicode strings, you need to use an Unicode library or the Unicode functionality provided by your operating system. Do not try to manipulate Unicode strings yourself, this a recipe for failure!

As for what do use: If your code is supposed to be cross platform, you may not rely on any encoding at all, as even though you use `wchar_t`, those may not be Unicode characters you are dealing with. In cross platform code, you cannot know the encoding your are dealing with, you can just read and write strings and pass strings between API calls, without trying to ever interpret them. You will have to use a cross platform Unicode library for cross-platform C++ code dealing with Unicode characters or manipulating Unicode strings.

If you develop for a specific platform only, go with the native encoding of the platform. Windows and Java have settled on UTF-16, so you'd use `wchar_t` on Windows, as that's the native system encoding. UNIX/Linux (which includes macOS and iOS) prefer UTF-8, so you'd use `char` on those platforms. At the end of the day, you can always convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 when needed but those conversions are costly and if you can avoid them, you should avoid them.

Note that up to Windows 95 and NT 3.1, Windows used UC-2, which is an encoding that can only represent a subset of Unicode (only 65535 characters), therefor each characters is always 16 bit. UC-2 is basically UTF-16 without surrogates and limited to characters in the basic plane.

Also note that while most Linux distributions uses UTF-8 as default today, it's still possible to set a different character encoding, so you may not rely on the fact that you are dealing with UTF-8 characters on Linux. Linux system API calls do not expect any specific encoding, they expect strings to be encoded according to the currently set locale which also sets the character sets and if they require anything else, they will convert the characters internally.