# How do i convert all alphabets to uppercase using transform ignoring digits?

Tags: c++, string, lambda, transform, toupper

I need to convert only letters in the string to uppercase and tried this piece of code which throws an error.

```
   s = "Dense-123-Sparse-999" 
   std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::toupper);
```

> Expected Output: "DENSE-123-SPARSE-999"

> "Error: non-void lambda does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]"

It's throwing an error since there are digits in the input string. How do I write a lambda function that converts characters to uppercase only if they are an alphabet and not a number?

something like this,

```
transform_if(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin, [](char c){ if(isalpha(c)return toupper(c);});
```

since C++ doesnt have **transform_if**, i'm looking for a  **one liner** with any other commands.

Comment: Be aware than in 2020 we have [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/), so consider using libraries like [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/). How would you handle some `é` or `à` or `€` or `°` or `§` sign? All of them are on my [AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) keyboard...

Comment: Do however read some [good C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Answer (score 0):

use a Lambda or a function

```
char upperize(char c)
{
    return toupper(c);
}
transform(s.begin(),s.end(),s.begin(),upperize);
```

```
transform(s.begin(),s.end(),s.begin(),[](char s){return toupper(s);});
cout<<s;
```

you can use isalpha also in addition

Comment: Won't work for `Être ou ne pas être` or your own name in Hindi, or my own name in Russian (`СТАРЫНКЕВИЧ`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897781/how-to-uppercase-lowercase-utf-8-characters-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, figured out `transform` and `for_each` with `lambda` code. works for letters without accents.

```
for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char &c) { c = (isalpha(c))? toupper(c):c; } ) ;
```

or

```
transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char &c) { return (isalpha(c))?toupper(c):c ; });
```

Thanks to [Basile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch)'s comments educating us on [UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/),  my code failed for below case:

```
input: "èéêrię"

output: "èéêRIę" (wrong)
```

will need to get back and search for UTF-8 library usage

Comment: See also [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) with `[](unsigned char c) { return std::toupper(c); }`

Comment: since you have two semi-colons, I think this does not count as a "one liner"