# Windows C Programming ReadFile CHAR or WCHAR

Tags: c, winapi

I am using ReadFile to read a pipe that has output from a command I run. However my understanding is ReadFile only reads the bytes and doesn't care if they are WCHAR or CHAR. It just reads the bytes.

I am trying to understand how would I go about determining if the bytes it reads from the buffer are WCHAR or CHAR so I can print properly. These bytes will be sent back to a Python server that will print.

Comment: AFAIK UNICODE support in `cmd.exe` is still broken and just a PITA.

Comment: Do you know of any other way to run CMD.EXE commands that support UNICODE? I was originally doing a wpopen but that spawns a cmd.exe window. Was switching to CreateProcess so I can hide it.

Comment: `_wpopen()` doesn't start a different command interpreter. It is just a version of `_popen()` that accepts UNICODE strings as command line. Do you actually know that the tools you call output UNICODE characters?

Comment: A dir command could output Unicode.

Comment: I don't think so. [Windows Console and Double/Multi Byte Character Set](https://www.curlybrace.com/words/2014/10/03/windows-console-and-doublemulti-byte-character-set/)

Comment: Oh that is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically reading from a stream, be it pipe of file or a in-memory buffer. So what you usually obtain is a pointer to a buffer in your program. It is up to your app logic to determine how to treat those bytes - as CHAR or as WCHAR, i.e. UTF-8 or UTF-16. Keep in mind that a buffer of CHAR elements can be cast to one of WCHAR and vice-versa.

I could suggest to use WHCAR to make your app UTF-16 compatible. Youc an refer to this question [In C++ when to use WCHAR and when to use CHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136837/in-c-when-to-use-wchar-and-when-to-use-char/46445846)